# Any drivers available for ODBC to Sybase that can be used with QTP?

Tags: odbc, sybase

I am looking for drivers that can be used to connect to sybase database from QTP.

Answer (score 2):

For Sybase ODBC drivers, see:

- http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/st/odbc-sybase-st/
- h t t p : / / w w w . sybase [dot] com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver (Servers and Clients tab)

For connection strings, see here: "h t t p : / / connectionstrings [dot] com

You might need to update one of the .INI files inside the Sybase folder. But, I can't remember which one :(.

However, once its done, you just need to use the correct connection string with ADO.

PS. Not able to post more than 1 link, thus, the workarounds.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Anshoo Arora